# Apple Cinema Display 27" with early 2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, displayport, cinema-display

I have a 13" early 2015 MacBook Pro with retina, and i am considering buying a second-hand 27" Apple Cinema Display.

The 27" LED with single cable with three connectors (Mini DisplayPort, MagSafe, and USB 2.0).

What cables/adapters do I need for this display to be able to use full resolution the screen has to offer?

Comment: Cinema displays have a couple connectors. What connection or input does the Cinema Display you are shopping contain? Can we also assume your MBP is 13” - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300 by editing 5is into your question, that will increase the chance someone will see the details.

Comment: @bmike i was thinking about one of the newer ones. The 27" LED with single cable with three connectors (Mini DisplayPort, MagSafe, and USB 2.0). Yes, its a 13" MBP with retina. https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715?locale=en_US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need any separate cable to connect the display to your 2015 MacBook Pro.

A Mini DisplayPort cable is attached to the display which can be plugged into one of 2 Thunderbolt 2 ports present on the left side of your MacBook Pro (besides MagSafe 2 connector).

Answer (score 1):

i justed dived in and bought the display and it works without any adapters.

It came with a mini displayport cable witch is compatible with thunderbolt 2 port on MBP right out of the box, no issues.

I will buy one more for total of two 27" cinema displays. :)